# Terminal list applications under Applications file

Tags: terminal

I try to list all the applications in the terminal. When I input `cd Applications/`, it doesn't work. However, when I input `cd /Applications/`, it works.
Does anyone know the differences between these two commands?

Comment: absolute paths start with a `/`, relative paths [to the current directory] don't

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second input uses an absolute path, while the first doesn't.

Supposing you're using MacOS, that has an `/Applications` folder in the root path, you can `cd Applications/` only if you are in the `/` path.

To see your current working directory you can use [pwd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd).

Answer (score 0):

`cd Applications` takes you in the `Applications` directory in the current directory. If the current directory is not the root directory (`/`), you won't have a subdirectory named `Applications`.

`cd /Applications` takes you in the subdirectory `Applications` of the directory `/`. It always exists on MacOS, so this command always works.

You can use `pwd` and any time to print the current directory (print working directory).